# how do i create my two tags under one header using xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

total newbie here and we are learning xml and xsl.
we were given a table and we turned it into xml.
however, i'm having a bit of a problem with xsl..

i have created this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="items.xsl" ?>

<sales>
    <sale>
        <id>1027</id>
        <firstName>Elaine</firstName>
        <lastName>Conner</lastName>
        <street>Ap #177-657 Pede Avenue</street>
        <city>Miller</city>
        <postCode>2143</postCode>
        <salesQuantity>100</salesQuantity>
        <productId>p101</productId>
    </sale>
    <sale>
        <id>1105</id>
        <firstName>Shelby</firstName>
        <lastName>Hinton</lastName>
        <street>P.O. Box 551, 5296 Penatibus Rd</street>
        <city>Granville</city>
        <postCode>2142</postCode>
        <salesQuantity>75</salesQuantity>
        <productId>p201</productId>
    </sale>
    <sale>
        <id>1122</id>
        <firstName>Bryar</firstName>
        <lastName>Weiss</lastName>
        <street>P.O. Box 511, 5053 Ac Avenue</street>
        <city>Campsie</city>
        <postCode>2153</postCode>
        <salesQuantity>150</salesQuantity>
        <productId>p105</productId>
    </sale>
```

the heading i have is
id, name, address, product name, sales quantity

how do i place my firstName and lastName inside the same header under name?
i got stuck with the second td tag as i don't know how to place both firstName and lastName in the same header?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Sales Department</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1>Sales Department Details</h1>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <th>Product Name</th>
                        <th>Sales Quantity</th>
                        <th>Sales Value</th>
                    </tr>

                    <xsl:for-each select="sales/sale">
                    <tr>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="id" /></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="firstName &#160" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `concat()` function of `XSLT` to concatenate the `firstName` and `lastName` inside the same `<td>`. Here the `firstName` and `lastName` are separated by a `space`. The syntax is as below.

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(firstName,' ',lastName)" />
```